# How to execute an observable conditionally? (Depending on a variable state in class level)

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6, rxjs-observables, rxjs-marbles

Can someone tell me if there is a clean way to return an observable conditionally, depending on a pre-defined condition?

Let us consider the following scenario,

```
isEditing = false;  // <---- This is a variable defined in the class level

return this.usersService.fetchInitialCreateData()  // <---- Observable 1
  .subscribe(
    (response) => {
      this.userBranches = response[0];
      this.userPermissionGroups = response[1];
      this.userRoles = response[2];

      return this.usersService.fetchInitialEditData(this.userId) // <---- Observable 2
        .subscribe(
          (response) => {
            this.isLoading = false;

            this.createUserForm.setValue({
              'primaryData': {
                'name': response.name,
                'username': response.username,
                'email': response.email,
                'contactNumber': response.contactNumber,
                'branch': response.branchCode,
                'role': response.role
              },
              'permissions': [],
              'userPassword': null,
              'userStatus': response.isActive ? 'active' : 'inactive'     
            });
          },
          (error) => {
            this.isLoading = false;
          }
        )
    }
  );
```

In the above example you can see two observables (marked as `Observable 1` and `Observable 2`) and a variable in the class level (marked as `This is a variable defined in the class level`)

Following are the conditions of the output I am trying to achieve,

1. `Observable 2` should be executed only upon receiving a success response from the `Observable 1`
2. From the two observables, the final return value should be `Observable 1`, if `isEditing = false`, the final return value should be `Observable 2` if `isEditing = true`

Whether the `Observable 1` is return or the `Observable 2` is returned as the final observable should be dependent upon the `isEditing` property.

I tried hard and hard, but I could not achieve this. Could someone please help me?

Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My brief suggestion:

```
obervable1.pipe(
  switchMap(obs1-result => forkJoin(of(obs1-result), observable2)),
  map([obs1-result, obs2-result] => isEditing ? obs1-result : obs2-result
).subscribe();
```

Please have a look at the example here: [working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-b38tka?file=index.ts)